# The shader on OpenGL ES 2.0 does not work the same way as the shader on WebGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl

I created a wave equation shader on shadertoy.com: You can see how it works by the link https://www.shadertoy.com/view/dtsyD2

Then I copied the code into my Android project working with GLES 2.0, changed `texture()` to `texture2D()` and also replaced `fragColor` and `fragCoord` with global `gl_FragColor` and `gl_FragCoord`. But the result doesn't look the same as on shadertoy (which works with WebGL).

Here's how it looks on Android:

[image: How does Android shader program look like]

What did I do wrong? Maybe there's something I didn't take into account.

Here is my code for vertex shaders (identical for both the main and buffer programs):

```c
attribute vec2 pos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(pos.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Here is my code for main fragment shader:

```c
precision lowp float;

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(iChannel0, uv);
}
```

Here is my code for buffer fragment shader:

```c
precision lowp float;

uniform vec3 iMouse;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform float iTime;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

const float delta = 1.0;

void main()
{
    float pressure = texture2D(iChannel0, gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy).x;
    float pVel = texture2D(iChannel0, gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy).y;

    float pright = texture2D(iChannel0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(1., 0.)) / iResolution.xy).x;
    float pleft = texture2D(iChannel0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(-1., 0.)) / iResolution.xy).x;
    float pup = texture2D(iChannel0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(0., 1.)) / iResolution.xy).x;
    float pdown = texture2D(iChannel0, (gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2(0., -1.)) / iResolution.xy).x;

    // Apply horizontal wave function
    pVel += delta * (-2.0 * pressure + pright + pleft) / 4.0;
    // Apply vertical wave function (these could just as easily have been one line)
    pVel += delta * (-2.0 * pressure + pup + pdown) / 4.0;

    // Change pressure by pressure velocity
    pressure += delta * pVel;

    // "Spring" motion. This makes the waves look more like water waves and less like sound waves.
    pVel -= 0.005 * delta * pressure;

    // Velocity damping so things eventually calm down
    pVel *= 1.0 - 0.002 * delta;

    // Pressure damping to prevent it from building up forever.
    pressure *= 0.999;

    //x = pressure. y = pressure velocity. Z and W = X and Y gradient
    gl_FragColor.xyzw = vec4(pressure, pVel, (pright - pleft) / 2.0, (pup - pdown) / 2.0);

    if (iMouse.z > 1.0) {
        float dist = distance(gl_FragCoord.xy, iMouse.xy);
        if (dist <= 20.0) {
            gl_FragColor.x += 1.0 - dist / 20.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The effect in Android (as shown in the animated gif) looks as if `float pVel = texture(iChannel0, fragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy).y` always retrieves a zero value. I suspect the problem is not in your GLSL code but in the surrounding code (Java?) that sets up the GL objects.

Comment: Try `#precision highp float` and see if that helps - most desktop GPUs will use fp32 for everything.

Comment: @ruud-helderman yes, setting `float  pVel = 0.0;` on shadertoy gives similar effect. Also `pVel = abs(pVel)` doesnt affect effect on android at all.

I create textures with `GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE` in Renderer, maybe it matters. I will research in this direction, thank you

Comment: @solidpixel unfortunately, `precision` does not affect the effect

Comment: So i learned that shadertoy's `fragColor` contains values in range `[-1; 1]`
And my android OpenGL ES 2.0's `gl_FragColor` contains values in range `[0; 1]`
So i did two things: 1. `gl_FragColor = vec4(0.5)` for the first frame. 2. mapping my values in buffer shader before writing to gl_FragColor.
it works better already, but something is still wrong (i have strange red noise in my android app).

Comment: also i changed
`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)`
to
`glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, null)`
and it seems to work 99% correctly, thank you for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: OpenGL's `GL_RGBA` format clamps values to the range `[0,1]`:
https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

So i did some adjustments to my shaders.

Mapping my values from `[-1; 1]` to `[0; 1]` in buffer shader before writing to gl_FragColor and changing

```kotlin
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null)
```

to

```kotlin
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA16F, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, null)
```

helped me. Also i had to switch my version from `2.0` to `3.0`

Also there is some difference in shaders because values are not in range `[-1; 1]`. But on 99% it works correctly.
Thank you Ruud Helderman for your assumption.

**Update.** I added blur into my fragment shader:

```c
precision lowp float;

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform sampler2D iChannel0;

void main()
{
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    gl_FragColor = blur(iChannel0, gl_FragCoord.xy);
}
```

So now it works perfectly. I used blur function from this shader: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XssSDs